# OSError: Starting path not found (dotenv-0.21.0-py3.9.egg) (python)

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, dotenv, python-dotenv

I'm developing a script in Python 3.9 that works perfectly on my personal PC. When I tried moving and running it on a server, it gives me the following error:

[there the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqGp1.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Laptop version: 3.10.7
server version: 3.9.0

I tried to install dotenv via pip manually, but it doesn't work.

also tried shebang but doesnt work.

Comment: Kindly post your error here. Without image

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same issue than [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77068121/1676127), where the problem was using `python setup.py install` instead of `pip install .`.